# How to delete Global Parameters using Powershell command

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a number of Global Parameters in DEV Azure Data Factory which is being used in many pipelines. I have deployed those Global parameters using ARM template to our QA environment.
Now I have deleted few parameters from Dev environment and when I re deployed the ARM template, those parameters are not getting deleted from QA environment.

I did not find any other way to delete from QA environment as we do not have delete permissions in QA.
Can you please suggest what are the next steps? I am looking for a powershell command way to delete those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $globalParametersFilePath,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $resourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $dataFactoryName
)

Import-Module Az.DataFactory
$newGlobalParameters = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.GlobalParameterSpecification]'

Write-Host "Getting global parameters JSON from: " $globalParametersFilePath
$globalParametersJson = Get-Content $globalParametersFilePath

Write-Host "Parsing JSON..."
$globalParametersObject = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($globalParametersJson)

# $gp in $factoryFileObject.properties.globalParameters.GetEnumerator()) 
# may  be used in case you use non-standard location for global parameters. It is not recommended. 
foreach ($gp in $globalParametersObject.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "Removing global parameter:" $gp.Key
    $globalParameterValue = $gp.Value.ToObject([Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.GlobalParameterSpecification])
    $newGlobalParameters.Remove($gp.Key)
}

$dataFactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $dataFactoryName
$dataFactory.GlobalParameters = $newGlobalParameters

Write-Host "Updating" $newGlobalParameters.Count "global parameters."

Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -InputObject $dataFactory -Force
```

Comment: @sac If the response is helpful , please accept the answer